# Click API returns a 401 error. RestAPI using same token does not

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting simple listing of clickwraps using the demo code found at https://developers.docusign.com/click-api/code-examples/clickwrap-getting and am receiving a 401 error.

I am receiving a 401 error trying to perform a listing of my clickwraps.

I have tried using a token generated by my golang esign library and using a tokens from the token generator.

Using the same tokens, I am able to make v2 eSignature RestAPI calls.

```sh
curl -i --request GET https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/v1/accounts/${APIAccountId}/clickwraps -a --header "Authorization: Bearer ${oAuthAccessToken}"  --header "Accept: application/json"
```

I receive the following response:HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 0f41a067-46c2-46a6-93fb-be8182010010
X-DocuSign-Node: SE1DFE187
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 22:47:58 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Do I need to use a scope other than "signature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you are having trouble Jim. I just found out that a recent code update that was in the works got released to our production environment. It requires you to specify the specific scope for click API in the request for token. This is because click is a separate product and requires you to have the correct scope definition.
You need to add `click.manage` in your authentication request.
We'll get the documentation updated ASAP

Instead of just `scope=signature%20organization_read` in the URL it redirects to
It would be `scope=signature%20organization_read%20click.manage`

Comment: The click.manage scope allowed me to create/update/list clickwraps but not list UserAgreements. 

Can I get a complete list of the click API scopes. I should be able to release the SDK after that.

Thanks

Comment: which API/endpoint are you calling to list the UserAgreements ?

Comment: So... that was my fault.  I was using clickwrap instead of clickwraps in the 5th part of the path.  It works fine now.

May want to change the error to a 404.

Comment: glad to hear it, and also very glad you are using the new click API!